# QProcess signals emitted after start called?

Tags: c++, qt

After `start()` is called on a `QProcess` object, what are the possible sequences of signal emissions that can follow to `started`, `errorOccurred` and `finished` ?

(Is the `started` signal always emitted?  Is the `finished` signal always emitted?
Are at least one of the three signals always emitted?  If `errorOccurred` is emitted can a `started` or `finished` signal be emitted after it?)

Comment: Could you show more information about your question? The signal 'finished' is emitted when the QProcess object quit.

Comment: @AllenZHU: See added clarifying questions

Answer (score 1):

When you call start() for a QProcess object, as soon as your process be started the **started** signal will be emit. If there occur any error in your process **errorOccurred** will emit and after finished of your process the **finished** signal will be called. But Finished signal always emit after some seconds so if you need to run a chain of commands you can use faster way instead of using finished signal like below:

```
QProcess *system_command = new QProcess();
system_command->start("/bin/bash");
system_command->waitForFinished(500);
system_command->write("ls -a\n");
```

**Update:**

No, the sequence isn't always the same. If your process started successfully and doesn't return an error it will emit **started** signal. Now if your process run a program that not finished or it is waiting for some command, finished signal will not emitted until that process finished successfully (It may never emit finished signal).

If your process encounter and error, **errorOccured** will emitted but **started** and **finished** signal will not emit.

**Example:**

If you run a bash with QProcess it will only emit started signal and finished signal never will emitted. Because it's waiting for other commands.

```
system_command->start("/bin/bash");
```

But if you run a bash with all of the commands that you want to run instantly, it will run and emit finished signal (in case of no error occurred).

```
readtimedatectl->start("/bin/sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "timedatectl");
```

Comment: See additional clarification added to question.